# Workflow not showing even when using pull request

Tags: github-actions

This is my YAML file (`<root directory>/.github/workflows/continuous-integration.yml`):

```yaml
---
name: CI Workflow

on:
  pull_request:

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.ref }}-ci-workflow

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "14"

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Build code
        run: npm run build

  test:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: "3.9"

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: pip install -r backend/requirements.txt

      - name: Test backend code using pytest
        run: pytest backend/tests

  build-and-push-docker:
    needs: test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Docker Build and Push
        env:
          DOCKER_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          DOCKER_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          # Build Docker image
          docker build -t my-app .

          # Tag Docker image
          docker tag my-app chulintian/is212-g4t1

          # Authenticate with Docker Hub
          echo "$DOCKER_ACCESS_TOKEN" |
            docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin

          # Push the Docker image to Docker Hub
          docker push chulintian/is212-g4t1
```

The workflow does not show on GitHub Actions. Previously, it showed up on GitHub Actions. But after that, I solved all errors identified by yamllint and changed the file name from pytest.yml to continuous-integration.yml. Then, the workflow on the GitHub Actions was still the original filename and didn't update or run. So, I deleted the workflow runs hoping that it will create a new workflow. But it didn't work either.

Comment: Workflow usually shows up when the source file is available on the main branch, and the following updates to workflow are visible if changes are done to the same file on a different branch. So when you delete, modify, or add a new workflow, it won't be directly visible under the Actions tab.